# How to render html page dynamically with all its includes from database

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot

we are developing application in spring boot where the html css and js are gonna render from database or some other storage location like cache.

Is there any framework already existing to implement this?

If yes for render .jsp file dynamically, how to render css and js dependency also dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

[This post shows](http://blog.kaczmarzyk.net/2015/01/04/loading-view-templates-from-database-with-thymeleaf/) how to implement a Thymeleaf view resolver that gets the templates from database. You can tweak it to your needs (jsp's or whatever)

Comment: They are using sping-boot. Therefore they only must add `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` to the dependencies.

Comment: The OP says he wants to render the templates from database. That's why he has to modify the template resolving mechanism.